# Access external (network) file with Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, networking

Hi I don't know if this has been asked so I'll try it.

I'm running a lot of VMWares and need to access them by path like in windows.
E.g. in the windows explorer I type: \192.168.1.122\c$ and then I login and have access to the folder.

So now I want to edit a particular file through Eclipse on that external VM. I can open the file in notepad or any editor I want except with Eclipse.

Through an Ant script I can copy files to the the specified VM, so I don't know why this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand the question, I think this is not really a java, eclipse or networking question. Regardless; VMWare lets you create your virtual OSes on several types of virtual hard drives, chosen during the creation of a VM, more info [on configuring virtual hard disks here](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/disks_config_ws.html). These are simply files that are interpreted by VM on runtime, and I don't think they are mounted anywhere. This goes, mind, for the file system of the VM itself.

If you want to access a network location which is running on your VM, like an apache server or the like, you can do so using [NAT](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_network21.html).

If you want to access files stored on your virtual harddrive, you can use a shared folder between the VM and host, on which more info [here](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html).